# Ordering the solr search results based on the indexed fields

Tags: solr, django-haystack, faceted-search

I have to order the search results from solr based on some fields which are already indexed. 
My current api request is like this without sorting.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/search/facets/?page=1&gender=Male&age__gte=19

And it gives the search results based on the indexed order. But I have to reorder this results based on the filed 'last_login' which is already indexed DateTimeField.

Here is my viewset

```
class ProfileSearchView(FacetMixin, HaystackViewSet): 
   index_models = [Profile]
   serializer_class = ProfileSearchSerializer
   pagination_class = PageNumberPagination

   facet_serializer_class = ProfileFacetSerializer
   filter_backends = [HaystackFilter]
   facet_filter_backends = [HaystackFilter, HaystackFacetFilter]

   def get_queryset(self, index_models=None):
      if not index_models:
          index_models = []
      queryset = super(ProfileSearchView,  self).get_queryset(index_models)
      queryset = queryset.order_by('-created_at')
      return queryset`
```

Here I have changed the default search order by 'created_at' value. But for the next request I have order based on the 'last_login' value. I have added a new parameter in my request like this

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/search/facets/?page=1&gender=Male&age__gte=19&sort='last_login'

but it gives me an error

> SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 400): [Reason: undefined field sort]

How can I achieve this ordering possible? Please help me with a solution.

Comment: try "sort=last_login desc" (or asc), no quotes around field name

Comment: @Persimmonium Thanks for your response. I have tried this but it still gives me the same response 'SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 400): [Reason: undefined field sort]'. This is what I'm trying http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/search/facets/?page=1&sort=last_login%20desc.

Comment: But the same request to solr http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&facet=true&sort=last_login%20desc works fine. Is this is the problem with my schema file?

Answer (score 0):

The URL you provided http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/search/facets/ is not direct SOLR URL. It must be your middle-ware. Since you have tried the query directly against Solr and it works, the problem must be somewhere in middle-ware layer.

Try to print or monitor or check logs to see what URL the midde-ware actually generates and compare it to the valid URL you know works.